# How to create a docker registry secret without passing the password on the command line?

Tags: kubernetes

According to this document

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

one could create a docker registry by running:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred \
--docker-server=<your-registry-server> \
--docker-username=<your-name> \
--docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

How to create a secret without entering the password as plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create a secret without passing on the commandline by reading it from file:

> ```
> $ kubectl create secret generic ssh-key-secret \
>   --from-file=ssh-privatekey=/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa \
>   --from-file=ssh-publickey=/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
> ```

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/ for more information.